# DYLD, [0x1] Library missing

Tags: php, macos

I've upgraded my mac to Catalina, and after doing so, I'm getting this popup over and over.
Tried upgrading brew, tried reinstalling php, but still...

[image]

(the title would translate to something similar to... php-fpm won't open due to an issue)

### Attaching here the entire log...

```
Process:               php-fpm [29416]
Path:                  /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.0/7.0.33/sbin/php-fpm
Identifier:            php-fpm
Version:               0
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           php-fpm [29416]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-07-08 15:30:10.113 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.5 (19F101)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        85FFB3B5-2E09-2D2F-57A9-8C3D57EE830D

Sleep/Wake UUID:       1B7701F9-55B5-4A58-84D4-58FD25F54B43

Time Awake Since Boot: 140000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       1900 seconds

System Integrity Protection: disabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x1] Library missing

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.64.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/php@7.0/sbin/php-fpm
  Reason: image not found

Binary Images:
       0x10e2ef000 -        0x10ec20ff3 +php-fpm (0) <21259CED-03EA-3E63-9AC6-982AFD8CF6DD> /usr/local/opt/php@7.0/sbin/php-fpm
       0x10edf4000 -        0x10ef47e87 +libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (0) <96B06B4B-AF12-3701-BB9C-5FA206454D03> /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
       0x10efc4000 -        0x10f003ff7 +libssl.1.0.0.dylib (0) <0F81118F-C6DD-3452-85EB-D1860B45848F> /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
       0x10f026000 -        0x10f036ff7 +libzip.5.dylib (0) <161074F6-B175-368D-AF4B-9E6551291FB8> /usr/local/opt/libzip/lib/libzip.5.dylib
       0x10f042000 -        0x10f0c1fff +libtidy.5.dylib (0) <AC0F3E07-91BC-32D5-9F06-6242F9198741> /usr/local/opt/tidy-html5/lib/libtidy.5.dylib
       0x10f0fe000 -        0x10f147ffb +libaspell.15.dylib (0) <BAE82D2E-F43F-3D5B-9437-F684E9F9F1AC> /usr/local/opt/aspell/lib/libaspell.15.dylib
       0x10f17a000 -        0x10f17bfff +libpspell.15.dylib (0) <E725D4DB-C809-386E-B8A5-57D7E8F09CF4> /usr/local/opt/aspell/lib/libpspell.15.dylib
       0x10f184000 -        0x10f1b9fff +libpq.5.dylib (0) <D63034BA-8DE6-3451-8B72-44E8F26EAE52> /usr/local/opt/libpq/lib/libpq.5.dylib
       0x10f1cd000 -        0x10f2a9fff +libsqlite3.0.dylib (0) <D4CC28D0-101B-3051-AB73-C26AD8F0AEEE> /usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib
       0x10f2cf000 -        0x10f31bffb +libsybdb.5.dylib (0) <D05508FE-BA7C-3EF1-ABA1-E8FDBD63C22F> /usr/local/opt/freetds/lib/libsybdb.5.dylib
       0x10f32d000 -        0x10f34aff3 +libmcrypt.4.dylib (0) <55DFB1B0-9430-3162-9607-E86F037B4162> /usr/local/opt/mcrypt/lib/libmcrypt.4.dylib
       0x10f35d000 -        0x10f362fff +libltdl.7.dylib (0) <50FE8108-144A-367A-9F15-7A1C918DD186> /usr/local/opt/libtool/lib/libltdl.7.dylib
       0x10f36a000 -        0x10f399fff +libldap-2.4.2.dylib (0) <0C09EDF0-280D-3311-84D7-D364AB4ACCF2> /usr/local/opt/openldap/lib/libldap-2.4.2.dylib
       0x10f3b5000 -        0x10f3bdff7 +liblber-2.4.2.dylib (0) <C9911478-1FB4-36A0-8D57-F01F34450BA8> /usr/local/opt/openldap/lib/liblber-2.4.2.dylib
       0x10f3c8000 -        0x10f423fc7 +libgmp.10.dylib (0) <6DACA437-97FF-3C9A-8F1A-6542952C4DD5> /usr/local/opt/gmp/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
       0x10f436000 -        0x10f43ffff +libintl.8.dylib (0) <65B896DF-857E-3C34-ABA1-8B7B45DB34F8> /usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib
       0x10f44c000 -        0x10f46fff7 +libpng16.16.dylib (0) <B7CE95CF-E67E-39EB-8DF5-B89849A02BDA> /usr/local/opt/libpng/lib/libpng16.16.dylib
       0x10f478000 -        0x10f4a6ffb +libjpeg.9.dylib (0) <5500CEBB-26F2-39DF-9364-8903B1C286CE> /usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib/libjpeg.9.dylib
       0x10f4af000 -        0x10f501ff7 +libwebp.7.dylib (0) <75A29427-0B1F-3A1A-8163-3D5450F98EC7> /usr/local/opt/webp/lib/libwebp.7.dylib
       0x10f511000 -        0x10f57bff7 +libcurl.4.dylib (0) <FBA0087F-E2A0-385D-BE4C-D18D97772930> /usr/local/opt/curl-openssl/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
       0x10f597000 -        0x10f5a3ffb +libcares.2.dylib (0) <B0BE1E79-5350-33A8-9E8F-3716F01B408F> /usr/local/opt/c-ares/lib/libcares.2.dylib
       0x10f5ac000 -        0x10f5c4ff3 +libnghttp2.14.dylib (0) <46FF6F67-9331-3981-90EF-A6EFB168C0BE> /usr/local/opt/nghttp2/lib/libnghttp2.14.dylib
       0x10f5d5000 -        0x10f5e8ffb +librtmp.1.dylib (0) <FF845FA5-C3B7-3C9D-9D59-9F2753628192> /usr/local/opt/rtmpdump/lib/librtmp.1.dylib
       0x10f5f0000 -        0x10f61affb +libssh2.1.dylib (0) <81C2DF33-6490-3714-A8DC-CC734B9C77B1> /usr/local/opt/libssh2/lib/libssh2.1.dylib
       0x10f627000 -        0x10f630ffb +libbrotlidec.1.dylib (0) <BD308DD7-FF31-37DA-9E4F-9C84322F8DAA> /usr/local/opt/brotli/lib/libbrotlidec.1.dylib
       0x10f637000 -        0x10f6b4ff7 +libfreetype.6.dylib (0) <1325785E-2A41-39FE-888B-539A55D8E8D9> /usr/local/opt/freetype/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
       0x1151b9000 -        0x11524aeff  dyld (750.5) <E4698FBD-806A-3396-B279-E685BA37430B> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff373aa000 -     0x7fff373bcff3  com.apple.Kerberos (3.0 - 1) <AE0E56CA-D924-3CC8-BBAA-8C6EEC3038BE> /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos
    0x7fff69a63000 -     0x7fff69a64fff  libSystem.B.dylib (1281.100.1) <B6FDA8A9-3D2B-3BD5-B5B0-57D311C0FF3D> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff69d3c000 -     0x7fff69d48fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib (44) <BF40E193-8856-39B7-98F8-7A17B328B1E9> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
    0x7fff69d49000 -     0x7fff69d9bfff  libc++.1.dylib (902.1) <AD0805FE-F98B-3E2F-B072-83782B22DAC9> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x7fff6a7d6000 -     0x7fff6a7f3fff  libedit.3.dylib (55) <7C3AAD74-F681-3295-9A5F-F7A2DFFC1FDB> /usr/lib/libedit.3.dylib
    0x7fff6a80e000 -     0x7fff6a81affb  libexslt.0.dylib (16.9) <AC76264B-F716-3479-AAEF-FCF6F1AC0FE8> /usr/lib/libexslt.0.dylib
    0x7fff6a83c000 -     0x7fff6a92cfff  libiconv.2.dylib (59) <F58FED71-6CCA-30E8-9A51-13E9B46E568D> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
    0x7fff6a92d000 -     0x7fff6ab84fff  libicucore.A.dylib (64260.0.1) <7B9204AC-EA14-3FF3-B6B9-4C85B37EED79> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff6b247000 -     0x7fff6b276fff  libncurses.5.4.dylib (57) <B0B09D08-A7C9-38E9-8BF4-E4F4882F93A6> /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib
    0x7fff6b9ca000 -     0x7fff6b9e2fff  libresolv.9.dylib (67.40.1) <B0F5D204-7EF2-3B0B-90EF-BB4D196FCC62> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
    0x7fff6be90000 -     0x7fff6bf72ff7  libxml2.2.dylib (33.3) <262EF7C6-7D83-3C01-863F-36E97F5ACD34> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
    0x7fff6bf9f000 -     0x7fff6bfb1ff3  libz.1.dylib (76) <DB120508-3BED-37A8-B439-5235EAB4618A> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
```

---

Any thoughts?
Hope you can help me out of this one.

Best,
Pablo

Comment: Hi there, could you please translate the entire problem text into English.

Comment: You have moved or removed `libicui18n.64.dylib` and have *not* relinked `/usr/local/opt/php@7.0/sbin/php-fpm`.

Comment: And how can I fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, finally I've just re-installed all php versions I had, as well as dylib with them. So far things are working fine.